# Assistance with a pop up message once progress bars reach 100%

Tags: popup, progress-bar

Please help. The code shown below allows a user to upload documents and then see a set of progress bars. Once the documents have been uploaded, I need a pop-up to say that the application has been submitted once the user hits the save bar. For the life of me, it's just not working, the pop-up doesn't display after the user hits save however the documents are saved to the DB correctly? See code below :

```
}, function errorCallback(response) {
        // called asynchronously if an error occurs
        // or server returns response with an error status.
        console.log("Funds not found:",response);
    });
};
factory.makeProgress = function(id,fileno){
if(i < 100){
    i = i + 1;
    console.log(i);
    $(id).css("width", i + "%").text(i + "%");
    console.log("Run makeprogress",fileno);
      if(fileno == 9)
     {
         console.log(id);
         if(i == 100)
         {
          console.log("i must be 100:",i);
           
               setTimeout(function() {
                 alert("The application has been successfully submitted.");
                 $window.location.href = "application";
                }, 1000);
         }
     }
    
}
```